# Trying to convert this VB.Net ThreadStart WCF code to C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, wcf

I have the following code in VB.Net.  It compiles and works as desired.

In my efforts to move to C#, whenever I work on a new project, I endeavour to use C#, however in this case, I'm clearly missing something.

```
Private m_Service As ServiceHost = Nothing

Public Function Start(ByVal AddressToConnect As String) As Thread
    Dim ServerProcess As New Thread(AddressOf WebService)

    ServerProcess.Start(AddressToConnect)

    Return ServerProcess
End Function

Private Sub WebService(ByVal AddressToListen As String) ' Address should be in the form: "http://localhost:8000/IHello"
    ' Define where to listen
    Dim Address As Uri = New Uri(AddressToListen)
    ' Define how to exchange messages
    Dim Binding As BasicHttpBinding = New BasicHttpBinding()

    ' When the connection is established, define what object is created
    m_Service = New ServiceHost(GetType(Worker), Address)

    ' Add an endpoint, passing the address, binding and contract
    m_Service.AddServiceEndpoint(GetType([Interface].IContract), Binding, Address)

    ' YOU MUST PERFORM THE FOLLOWING BEFORE YOU ATTEMPT TO OPEN THE CONNECTION
    ' netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:80/MyUri user=DOMAIN\user

    ' Begin listening for connections
    m_Service.Open()
    Console.WriteLine("WCF Service started")
End Sub

Public Sub [Stop]()
    m_Service.Close()
    m_Service = Nothing
End Sub
```

The same in C# from one of those VB to C# conversion sites says the following should work:

```
private ServiceHost _Service = null;

public Thread Start(string AddressToConnect)
{

    Thread ServerProcess = new Thread(new EventHandler(WebService));
    ServerProcess.Start(AddressToConnect);
    return ServerProcess;
}


private void WebService(string AddressToListen)
{
    //  Address should be in the form: "http://localhost:8000/IHello"
    //  Define where to listen
    Uri Address = new Uri(AddressToListen);
    //  Define how to exchange messages

    BasicHttpBinding Binding = new BasicHttpBinding();

    //  When the connection is established, define what object is created
    _Service = new ServiceHost(typeof(Worker), Address);

    //  Add an endpoint, passing the address, binding and contract
    _Service.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(Interface.IContract), Binding, Address);

    //  YOU MUST PERFORM THE FOLLOWING BEFORE YOU ATTEMPT TO OPEN THE CONNECTION
    //  netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:80/MyUri user=DOMAIN\user

    //  Begin listening for connections
    _Service.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("WCF Service started");
}

public void Stop()
{
    _Service.Close();
    _Service = null;
}
```

The problem is that the compiler complains about:
    Thread ServerProcess = new Thread(new EventHandler(WebService));

"No overload for WebService matches delegate EventHandler"

What am I doing wrong?  What should the C# code be?

Apologies for what should be an easy question, but I've always struggled with delegates.

--EDIT--

Thanks to Markus, this is what I have now:

```
public Thread Start(string AddressToConnect)
    {
        Thread ServerProcess = new Thread(WebService);

        ServerProcess.Start(AddressToConnect);

        return ServerProcess;
    }
```

And the WebService method is now:

```
private void WebService(object AddressToListen)
    {
        //  Address should be in the form: "http://localhost:8000/IHello"
        //  Define where to listen
        Uri Address = new Uri((string)AddressToListen);
        //  Define how to exchange messages
...
```

Comment: Would this be the equivalent?
 
 public Task Start(string AddressToConnect)
 {
  Task t = new Task(() =>
  {
   WebService(AddressToConnect);
  });

  t.Start();

  return t;
 }

Comment: `new Thread(WebService(AddressToConnect)); ` try that... Then start it `ServerProcess.Start();`...

Comment: @Codexer:  I tried Thread t = new Thread(WebServiceAddressToConnect));t.Start();return t; and that doesn't compile

Comment: my typeo `new Thread(WebService);` then `ServerProcess.Start(AddressToConnect);`... Also the code above u posted isnt what i posted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the `AddressOf` operator. It is not required in C#:

```
Thread ServerProcess = new Thread(WebService);
```

One thing to note though is that the method provided needs to match the signature of [`ParameterizedThreadStart`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart(v=vs.110).aspx). This takes an object as parameter  so you need to change the signature of your WebService method:

```
private void WebService(object AddressToListen)
```

In the method, you have to convert the object to a string.

Comment: I added a new StartThread method, and changed the signature as you suggested, and it does indeed compile.  I will post up what I came up with as you have indeed provided enough information for me to work out the rest.